# Remove decimals from listview subitem

Tags: c#, listview, formatting, format

My listview is being populated by a sql query.  The data on sql is an integer "25, 4, 9" etc.  But when added to listview its "25.000, 4.000" etc.  I've tried using the ("0.#") format but it just tells me it cannot convert to integer. The subitem I'm having the issue with is `[VOID_LENGTH]`

```
            foreach (Dictionary<string, string> d in resultHistory)
            {
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(d["LOT_NO"]);
                lvi.SubItems.Add(d["SERIAL_NO"]);
                lvi.SubItems.Add(d["DATE_TIME"]);
                lvi.SubItems.Add(d["VOID_LOC"]);
                lvi.SubItems.Add(d["VOID_LENGTH"]);
                lvi.SubItems.Add(d["EMPL_ID"]);

                listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
            }
```

The query

```
public List<Dictionary<string, string>> GetVoid(string VoidDate, bool orderByDate = false)
    {
        List<Dictionary<string, string>> results = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        string query = "";
        List<OleDbParameter> queryParameters = new List<OleDbParameter>();

        query = "SELECT LOT_NO, SERIAL_NO, DATE_TIME, VOID_LOC, VOID_LENGTH, EMPL_ID ";
        query += "FROM MPCS.BRAZE_VOIDS ";
        query += "WHERE TRUNC(DATE_TIME) = TO_DATE(?, 'dd-MON-yy')";

        if (orderByDate)
        {
            query += " order by INS_UPD_TIMESTAMP asc, VOID_LOC desc";
        }

        queryParameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("DATE_TIME", VoidDate));

        results = this.ExecuteParameterQuery(query, queryParameters);
        return (results);
    }
```

Comment: can you show us  your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column type in DB is decimal(n,3) I think, you can cast it into int while select. Modify select query part like this

```
cast(VOID_LENGTH as int) as VOID_LENGTH
```

Comment: `cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem`

Comment: That did it.  Thank you so much.